# Execute module-qualified function inside perl regex substitution?

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, substitution

I have the following perl one-liner to convert `/path/to/file.txt` to `/path/to/`

```
echo "/path/to/file.txt" | perl -pe 's{(.*)}{File::Basename->dirname($1)}ge'
```

but I'm missing something in my invocation of `File::Basename->dirname()`, causing the following error:

```
Can't locate object method "dirname" via package "File::Basename" (perhaps you forgot to load "File::Basename"?) at -e line 1, <> line 1.
```

What am I missing?

(I know I can just use `dirname` from bash but I'm trying to do something more complicated with perl than what this stripped down example shows).

Comment: answer for my future copy-paste needs: `echo "/path/to/file.txt" | perl -MFile::Basename -pe 's{([^\n]+)}{dirname($1)}ge'`

Comment: Note that this way you are importing _all_ functions from this module. To import (only) a specific one, use `-MModule=func`

Comment: Good to know. As it turns out I need to use `dirname` AND `basename` so that worked out conveniently :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you had `<button>` in the replacement string, but you've removed that now so it should work

The replacement string must be a valid Perl expression if you're using the `/e` modifier, and

```
<button>File::Basename->dirname($1)
```

isn't valid Perl

---

The correct command would be:

```
echo "/path/to/file.txt" | perl -pe 'use File::Basename 'dirname'; s{([^\n]+)}{dirname($1)}ge'
```

Comment: After removing `button`, I get `Can't locate object method "dirname" via package "File::Basename" (perhaps you forgot to load "File::Basename"?) at -e line 1, <> line 1.` . I'll update the question.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation for `File::Basename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename). The module *exports* `dirname`; it's not an object oriented module. So you need `use File::Basename 'dirname'` and then you can call it with just `dirname($1)`.

Comment: ...which, in one-liner subsitution mode, is only possible with `perl -M` I guess. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No. You can put `use File::Basename 'dirname';` inside the quotes if you like. It's exactly the same as adding `-MFile::Basename=dirname` as an option

Comment: Oh, got it. I'll update your answer with the correction for my exact command. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmmm, I do want `<button>` ultimately (I'm trying to generate some HTML). I guess I should create a  separate question for that, but basically I need to mix a function call with plain text in the output. How simple is this to do?

Comment: In answer to my last question, I would use `'<button>' . dirname($1)`

Comment: ...so the full statement would be `echo "/path/to/file.txt" | perl -MFile::Basename=dirname  -pe 's{([^\n]+)}{"<button>".dirname($1)."</button>"}ges' `

Answer (score 1):

Load a module with `-MModName=func`

```
perl -MFile::Basename=dirname -pe 's{(.*)}{dirname($1)}ge'
```

---

The [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) module exports all its functions by default so you don't need `=dirname` above.  But this varies between modules, and mostly you do need to import symbols.  For more on how to do that in a one-liner, find the `-M` switch in [Command Switches in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).

Comment: Bingo, I forgot the module isn't loaded without `-M`.

Comment: Just to expand on this (I'm trying to create some HTML), you can mix text with evaluation with `@{dirname($1)}` without the `/e` switch. The only cost is that I can't use mu usual `s{}{}g` structure and have to revert to the (inferior but) more common `s//g` structure

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat  It sounds like you may want to switch to a script ... ? It's all going to suddenly become far easier :)

Comment: I know where you're coming from. Currently I'm waging a war against "monster monoliths" as I call them and (over?) utilizing pipes for composability to see how far Doug McIlroy's "Unix Philosophy" can take me when doing rapid prototyping. But yes it's approaching its limits.

Answer (score 1):

Error #1:

Like the message suggests (*perhaps you forgot to load "File::Basename"?*), you need to load File::Basename.

```
perl -pe'use File::Basename; ...'
```

or

```
perl -MFile::Basename -pe'...'
```

---

Error #2:

`dirname` is not a method, so `File::Basename->dirname` is incorrect. It needs to be called as `File::Basename::dirname`.

```
perl -MFile::Basename -pe's{(.*)}{File::Basename::dirname($1)}ge'
```

You could also import `dirname`.

```
perl -MFile::Basename=dirname -pe's{(.*)}{dirname($1)}ge'
```

Fortunately, File::Basename exports `dirname` by default, so you can simply use

```
perl -MFile::Basename -pe's{(.*)}{dirname($1)}ge'
```

Comment: Thanks for all the alternatives, it's good to know for finding personal preferences. I wish I could mark all 3 answers correct.